# is it bad to use public static fields/variables?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, static, android-memory

I started learning about Android Development, and I read about static variables are bad and may leak memory because they are not garbage collectable.

I've used some in certain situations, but I am so concerned it may leak memory.

Can someone please look at my code below and see if they leak memory or not?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static boolean IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN;
public static ImageView image;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);        
        IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN = true;

    ....

    ....

    VoiceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
       .....
    };
    registerReceiver(VoiceReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadCastReceivers.VoiceIntent));

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  
    unregisterReceiver(VoiceReceiver);          
    IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN = false;
    }   
}
```

Picture.java

```
MainActivity.image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

.....

.....

BroadCast.java

```
if (!MainAcitivty.IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN) {
    //start an activity
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainAcitivty.class);            
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent2); 
    handler=  new Handler();
    MyPostDelay = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() { 
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(VoiceIntent));
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(MyPostDelay, 300);
}
else
{
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(VoiceleIntent));
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, caching views is a bad idea as they are designed to be recreated and you can replace that public boolean with a simple getter which returns true or false based on the state of the object. In general, it's okay to use static combined with final to create values that will never change. If you can't answer the question "Should this always be accessible from everywhere?" with a yes, don't make public static variables and methods.

Comment: if you scared, persist your data.. and putting your statics variables in an activity can cause your receiver to behave some type of way.. singletons, or the cheap sharedpreference.. and holding an imageview, is not that good, create a bitmap from the imageview rather.. you can google it.goes something like `imageView.buildDrawingCache()`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate for your comment.  If I use SharedPreferences to save IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN boolean, then retrieve it in BroadCast, it should be good, right?  When retrieving the IS_ACTIVITY_OPEN boolean from SharedPreferences, the new boolean value will be garbage collectable, correct?   Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) article on the Android Developers Blog. Keeping a **static** field holding a Context, or any other class that has a (strong) reference to a Context (such as any View) will mean that the garbage collector will not be able to reclaim the storage allocated by the Context. If the Context is an Application, thats OK because they live for as long as your app does and wouldn't be garbage collected anyway. But in case of Views, Context is likely an Activity which should be garbage collected as soon as possible.

That doesn't mean that all **static** fields will catastrophically leak memory. If they're primitive types, or simple classes, or even more complex classes with weak references to other classes, they might not prevent the garbage collector from reclaiming a lot of memory. But generally having **static** and  especially **public static** fields is a code smell and should probably be avoided so the code is easier to maintain later.

Comment: can you please help me with this one too please?  I've been using one String or int throughout the activity.  For example, I initialize private String imagePath right at the beginning, and I use it in different methods.  For example, imagePath = "....."  and then in another method, I call File file = new File(imagePath).  I am afraid this idea may leak memory.  Basically, this imagePath is floating around and being reused over and over, Is it bad?