# Binary XML Inflate Error on PopupMenu.show() Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I'm trying to inflate a simple PopupMenu for rename/delete options when a RecylerView item is longClicked. For some reason i'm getting an XML inflate error when I call `mPopup.show()` after loading my xml file into the inflater.

I use similar logic elsewhere in my app to make a PopupMenu and it works fine. I've even tried loading the working PopupMenu from an unrelated part of the app into this inflater and I see the same `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1` error in logcat, so maybe the XML file isn't the problem?

How can I get this PopupMenu to inflate and show itself?

**Fatal Exception Logcat**

```
05-31 23:02:27.421 19597-20019/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.foo, PID: 19597
                                               android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005d a=-1}
                                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005d a=-1}
                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:761)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7060)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7241)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:438)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:370)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:369)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233)
                                                   at com.example.foo.FragmentChordMenu.showChordOptionsMenu(FragmentChordMenu.java:132)
                                                   at com.example.foo.CustomChordAdapter$ChordViewHolder$2.onLongClick(CustomChordAdapter.java:138)
                                                   at android.view.View.performLongClickInternal(View.java:5687)
                                                   at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5645)
                                                   at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5663)
                                                   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:22234)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**FragmentActivity**

```
public class FragmentChordMenu extends Fragment implements CustomChordAdapter.onItemClickListener {    
    private static RecyclerView mCustomChordList;
    private static CustomChordAdapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private static Context mContext;

    private FloatingActionButton mFAB;
    private View mPopupView;
    private PopupWindow mCustomChordMenu;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new CustomChordAdapter(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();   //stores application context for later use in fragment without risk
                                                            //of detachment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_chord, container, false);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ...

        mFAB = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.addChord);
        mFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCustomChordMenu.showAtLocation(mPopupView, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 10);
                mCustomChordList = (RecyclerView) mPopupView.findViewById(R.id.rv_userChords);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                mCustomChordList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                mCustomChordList.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public static void showChordOptionsMenu(final int position){
        View anchorView = mCustomChordList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
        PopupMenu mPopup = new PopupMenu(mContext, anchorView);
        mPopup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.delete:
                        mRecyclerViewAdapter.deleteChord(position);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.rename:
                        Log.d("FragmentChordMenu: ", "Rename clicked");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuInflater popupInflater = mPopup.getMenuInflater();
        popupInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_delete_chord, mPopup.getMenu());
        mPopup.show();              //ERROR HERE
    }

    ...
}
```

**PopupMenu XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/rename"
        android:title="@string/rename"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="@string/delete"/>
</menu>
```

**FragmentActivity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/chordMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/chordButtons"
                android:orientation="vertical"  >
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                android:id="@+id/addChord"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                app:useCompatPadding="false"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();` - I would bet that that's your problem. You're using the v7 appcompat `PopupMenu`, and the application `Context` won't have the right theme resources set on it. Just use `getActivity()`. You really don't need to keep a `Context` field, btw. You can call `getActivity()` wherever you need one.

Comment: @MikeM. how can I use getActivity() in a non-static context? showChordOptionsMenu() is a static method, hence the issue.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice it was. Yeah, you really don't want to keep all those `static` members in your `Fragment` class. Normally, you'd wanna add a `Context` parameter to the method to pass one in, but that method is using other static members with `Context`s, so it's a moot point here. You'd have to redesign how you're communicating with that `Fragment`. Anyhoo, the current issue is likely the wrong `Context`, so just removing the `getApplicationContext()` call in the code you have now will let you know if that is indeed the issue.

Comment: @MikeM. Good suggestion, however, i'm getting a new runtime error now. `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f847ac3 is not valid; is your activity running?` I think i might be trying to secure the wrong context, I think I should instead be trying to get the context of the PopupWindow this transaction occurs in. Do you know how I would do this? Or rather, what the source of the issue is?

Comment: Oh, you're trying to show a `PopupMenu` from a `PopupWindow`? I don't think that's gonna work. I don't believe you can anchor a popup to another popup.

Comment: Uh oh. I'll ask a new question about this. Hopefully its doable, I want to avoid major code rework.

Comment: Just use a `Dialog` instead of the `PopupWindow`.

Comment: That's undesirable for a few reasons, the biggest being that I don't need the action buttons or the interaction-with-parent-view methods that the Dialog class provides.

Comment: `Dialog`s don't have any buttons - or any kind of `View` - by default. I think you're thinking of `AlertDialog`. You can make it be just a floating `RecyclerView`, if you want. I don't know what you mean by "interaction-with-parent-view methods".

Comment: I suppose I was thinking about this answer "If you want to add more control and feedback between your View then use a Dialog. If you, like me, want master control over everything, I would suggest a PopupWindow since it has fewer user-evident default methods to override." from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710361/when-to-use-android-popupwindow-vs-dialog. Are you sure that a PopupMenu works when anchored to a dialog? If there really isn't much trade off I'll use that instead.

Comment: Sure, I've done it before. Of course, there's a way you can find out for certain yourself. :-) Looks like you'd have to change all of about three lines of code.

Comment: Thanks. If you post the suggested changes for the ~3 relevant lines I will award you the accepted answer.

Comment: You can actually do it rather simply with `AlertDialog`; just don't setup any buttons. Remove/comment out the `mCustomChordMenu.showAtLocation()` line, and insert - just as an example - `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(mPopupView).show();`.

Comment: Amazing, works. Thanks. If you want rep post this so I can accept it.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. Will do. It'll be a little bit before I get a chance to put an answer together, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the immediate issue here - the `InflateException` - was using the application `Context` for an appcompat-v7 `PopupMenu`.

```
mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
...
PopupMenu mPopup = new PopupMenu(mContext, anchorView);
```

That `Context` won't have the correct theme resources set for a v7 widget, leading to the `InflateException`. The `Activity` does have the appropriate theme, though, and using that instead solves that particular issue.

```
mContext = getActivity();
```

---

After fixing that, however, a `WindowManager$BadTokenException` came up due to the `PopupMenu` being passed an anchor `View` from a `PopupWindow`. Popups must be anchored to a `View` in a top-level `Window`, and the `Popup*` classes are basically simple `View`s, thus the Exception.

A simple solution for this is to replace the `PopupWindow` with a `Dialog`, which does have a `Window`. For example:

```
AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(mPopupView).show();
```

---

Lastly, I would suggest that you modify your setup to remove the need for the `static` members in your `Fragment` class. Those `static` fields are likely to cause memory leaks, and your IDE may very well be warning you of that now. A listener interface similar to the one you have in `CustomChordAdapter` would suffice.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about the last part of your answer; do you have a link to any resources about preventing memory leaks in static members?

Comment: Hmm, not really. I mean, there's pretty much only two ways to prevent leaks with them: 1.) Don't use them. 2.) Make sure you set the references to null as soon as you're done with them. If you're just looking for general info on static leaks and such, there's been volumes written on it. Here are some on-site posts, but you might find more thorough explanations on some blogs or tutorials or whatnot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908685, https://stackoverflow.com/a/641473, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091135. That last one has a link to an old Android Developers Blog page on it.

Comment: Saved my day, thank you so much. I had a similar issue when trying to inflate a layout in my adapter, and after having read your comment I realized I created this adapter with application's Context instead of Activity's.